# as I initialize the code to paintcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to initialize and focus on my screen the following code made ​​with paint code, but I have not managed to find the right way always gives me an error

```
 import UIKit

 public class IndicadorCirculo : NSObject {

//// Drawing Methods

public class func drawCanvas2(#indicadro: CGFloat) {
    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //// Color Declarations
    let optimo = UIColor(red: 0.350, green: 0.800, blue: 0.320, alpha: 1.000)

    //// Oval 2 Drawing
    var oval2Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(48, 107, 237, 244))
    optimo.setFill()
    oval2Path.fill()
    UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
    oval2Path.lineWidth = 8
    oval2Path.stroke()


    //// Oval Drawing
    var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(91, 152, 151, 154))
    UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()
    UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
    ovalPath.lineWidth = 8
    ovalPath.stroke()


    //// Bezier Drawing
    var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 8
    bezierPath.stroke()


    //// Bezier 2 Drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 166.57, 231.46)
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, -indicadro * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180)

    var bezier2Path = UIBezierPath()
    bezier2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0.43, -124.22))
    bezier2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0.43, -79.28), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0.43, -77.68), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(0.43, -79.28))
    UIColor.darkGrayColor().setStroke()
    bezier2Path.lineWidth = 8
    bezier2Path.stroke()

    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}

  }

  @objc protocol StyleKitSettableImage {
  func setImage(image: UIImage!)
 }

 @objc protocol StyleKitSettableSelectedImage {
func setSelectedImage(image: UIImage!)
}
```

I used the init function and frame did not work , I appreciate if you could help

Thanks.

Comment: You have no graphics context. Drawing must happen in a graphics context. (The notion "initialize and focus on my screen" means nothing.)

Comment: thanks Matt, You have no graphics context. Drawing must happen in a graphics context. (The notion "initialize and focus on my screen" means nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt says, you have no graphics context. To get your circle onscreen, you need to have a UIView. There is a method drawRect() in UIView which is automatically called whenever the view needs to be drawn. (Never call drawRect() directly in your code.)

DrawRect() gives you access to the view's current drawing context.

Try this:

1. Create a new swift file CirculoView as a subclass of UIView.
2. In your storyboard, add a new UIView to your main view. Change the class of this UIView to CirculoView.
3. Change CirculoView.swift to have your code from PaintCode in the drawRect() method.

Here's the code

```
import UIKit

class CirculoView: UIView {

var indicadro:CGFloat = 0 {
  didSet {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
  }
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

  //// General Declarations
  let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

  //// Color Declarations
  let optimo = UIColor(red: 0.350, green: 0.800, blue: 0.320, alpha: 1.000)

  //// Oval 2 Drawing
  var oval2Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(48, 107, 237, 244))
  optimo.setFill()
  oval2Path.fill()
  UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
  oval2Path.lineWidth = 8
  oval2Path.stroke()


  //// Oval Drawing
  var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(91, 152, 151, 154))
  UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
  ovalPath.fill()
  UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
  ovalPath.lineWidth = 8
  ovalPath.stroke()


  //// Bezier Drawing
  var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
  UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
  bezierPath.lineWidth = 8
  bezierPath.stroke()


  //// Bezier 2 Drawing
  CGContextSaveGState(context)
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 166.57, 231.46)
  CGContextRotateCTM(context, -indicadro * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180)

  var bezier2Path = UIBezierPath()
  bezier2Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0.43, -124.22))
  bezier2Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(0.43, -79.28), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0.43, -77.68), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(0.43, -79.28))
  UIColor.darkGrayColor().setStroke()
  bezier2Path.lineWidth = 8
  bezier2Path.stroke()

  CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}
}
```

I just ran that and got a green circle with blue stroke in the view.